# Mac Catalyst - Dragging to an inactive window

Tags: ios, macos, mac-catalyst

An iPad app that accepts `UIImage` objects as dragging items has been built for macOS via Catalyst in Xcode 11b6.

When I drag images from Finder or Photos I am finding that my app must first be placed in the foreground to accept the drag.

This works.

- Foreground my app.
- Drag image into app. Drop is accepted.

This doesn't work.

- Background my app.
- Drag image into app. No drop handlers are triggered, drop is NOT accepted.

Expected behaviour is that content can be dragged into an inactive window like any Cocoa app.

I am implementing `UIDropInteractionDelegate`.

```
extension MyViewController: UIDropInteractionDelegate {

  func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    return session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self)
  }

  func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
    //only want external app sessions
    if session.localDragSession == nil {
      return UIDropProposal(operation: .copy)
    }
    return UIDropProposal(operation: .cancel)
  }

}
```

Is this a Catalyst beta quirk or is some extra `UIWindow`/`UIScene` magic required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this was a Catalina bug that was fixed in one of the latest betas. I'm running Beta 7 and this issue no longer exists.